# How can i use a for loop in javascript to add HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm making a little gallery in my website and it contains lots of pictures, how can I use a for loop to add the `li` in my website.

This is my HTML right now and instead of all those `<li>` I would like a `for` loop.
HTML:

```
<div id="pictureBlock">
    <div id="three-columns" class="grid-container">
        <ul class="rig columns-3">
            <li><img src="images/1.jpg" /></li>
            <li><img src="images/2.jpg" /></li>
            <li><img src="images/3.jpg" /></li>
            <li><img src="images/4.jpg" /></li>
            <li><img src="images/5.jpg" /></li>
            <li><img src="images/6.jpg" /></li>
            <li><img src="images/7.jpg" /></li>
            <li><img src="images/8.jpg" /></li>
            <li><img src="images/9.jpg" /></li>
            <li><img src="images/10.jpg" /></li>
            <li><img src="images/11.jpg" /></li>
            <li><img src="images/12.jpg" /></li>
            <li><img src="images/13.jpg" /></li>
            <li><img src="images/14.jpg" /></li>
            <li><img src="images/15.jpg" /></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: are you getting array of images and want to display them in `li`s?

Comment: li length is fixed ? or it depend on some amount of value ?

Comment: Do you want display all these images using JavaScript. Images do you want to print are hard coded or some back end is provided for displaying images.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using jQuery:

```
var ul = $('ul.rig');
var count = 15; // number of images

for(var i = 1; i <= count; i++) {
    ul.append('<li><img src="images/' + i + '.jpg"></li>');
}
```

Comment: what's that first line for ?

Answer (score 2):

```js
<div id="pictureBlock">
    <div id="three-columns" class="grid-container">
        <ul class="rig columns-3" id="gallery">
        
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    var gal = document.getElementById('gallery');
    

    for (var i = 1; i < 15 ; i++) {
        gal.innerHTML += "<li><img src='images/" + i + ".jpg' /></li>";
    };

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the easiest way would be using [jQuery](https://jquery.com/):

```js
var numberOfImages = 15;
var $container = $("#pictureBlock ul");
for (var i=1; i<=numberOfImages; i++) {
  $container.append('<li><img src="images/'+i+'.jpg" /></li>');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="pictureBlock">
    <div id="three-columns" class="grid-container">
        <ul class="rig columns-3"></ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

**01 - If your image file name are ordered by number and are in same location**

```
// Define number of images
var numImages = 15;

// Get the div you want to add element to
var rigDiv = $(".rig");

// Loop through images and add them to target div
for (var i=1; i <= numImages; i++) {
    var element = '<li><img src="images/' + i + '.jpg" /></li>';
    rigDiv.append(element);
}
```

**02 - If your image file name are not in order and are not in same directory**

```
// Define images array
var images = [
  'images/1.jpg',
  'images/2.jpg',
  ....
  'images/10.jpg'
];

// Get the div you want to add element to
var rigDiv = $(".rig");

// Loop through images and add them to target div
for(var image of images){
    var element = '<li><img src="' + image + '" /></li>';
    rigDiv.append(element);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply you can use a for loop,

```js
for (var i = 1; i < 16; i++) {
  $('ul.rig').append('<li><img src="images/' + i + '.jpg" /></li>')
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="pictureBlock">
  <div id="three-columns" class="grid-container">
    <ul class="rig columns-3">
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery you could do something like in this Fiddle i just created:

```
var pictures = [ "1", "2" ];

$.each(pictures, function(value) {
    $(".rig").append("<li><img src='images/" + value + ".jpg' /></li>");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wd09ccpa/

In the var pictures would have to be some list of the pictures you have.

Answer (score 0):

Jquery for the win:

```
for(var i = 1; i <= count; i++) {
   $('ul.rig').append("<li><img src='images/'+i+'.jpg'></li>");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var count = 15;
for(let i=1; i<=count; i++){
    $("ul").append('<li><img src="images/'+ i +'.jpg" /></li>');
}
```